# Polynomial time algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian walk in a graph

Tags: algorithm, np-complete

Is there a polynomial time algorithm for finding a Hamiltonian walk in a graph?

My algorithm is N factorial and is really slow.

Comment: I understand that finding a Hamiltonian path is an NP-complete problem. 

Is finding a Hamiltonian circuit the same, or has it been solved?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You just asked the [million dollar question](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP).  Finding a Hamilton path is an NP-complete problem.  Some NP-hard problems can be solved in polynomial time using dynamic programming, but (to my knowledge) this is not one of them.

Comment: NP-hard problems have yet to be solved in polynomial time, that is still the million-dollar question. They have be solved in pseudo-polynomial time (see the wikipedia page on Knapsack problem for more details).

Comment: There are no known polynomial time algorithms for any of the NP-complete problems; if there were just one algorithm for one of the problems, all the other NP-complete problems would be reducible to it in polynomial time. I think what hazzen is referring to is the fact that some problems, such as Knapsack, can be approximated quite well in polynomial time. However, the closer you get to a perfect approximation, the further you get from polynomial.

Comment: Can you name the problem and describe the algorithm? We are of course interested.

Comment: Many NP-complete problems can be solved using dynamic programming.  Consider the problem of string alignment (edit distance). O(k^n) with a naive implementation, but O(n^2) using dynamic programming.  Generically, any problem which exhibits optimal substructure and overlapping subproblems can be reduced in complexity using memoization, which is what dynamic programming does.  Wikipedia has a decent explanation and some examples.

Comment: It's important to note that dynamic programming doesn't really provide an algorithm for solving NP-complete problems in polynomial time, it's just exploiting the structure of a very specific sub-class of problems to throw out redundant work.  The technique is *not* applicable to the general class of NP-complete problems.  It would be a terrific result if it were.  :-)

Comment: Still, part of your answer is incorrect - there is no known NP-hard problem that can be solved in polynomial time. Edit distance is not NP-hard (unless P = NP); it is in P. (Some NP problems can be solved in polynomial time, and then they are in the subset called P.)

Answer (score 21):

In general, as the (decision version of the) Hamiltonian Path problem is NP-complete, you cannot hope to get a polynomial-time algorithm for finding Hamiltonian paths. You can slightly speed it up with the usual N! → N<sup>2</sup>2<sup>N</sup> dynamic programming trick (compute hp[v][w][S] = "is there a path that has endpoints v and w and whose vertices are the subset S" for every subset S and every two vertices v and w in it using DP), but that's still exponential.

However, there are many special kinds of graphs for which Hamiltonian paths will always exist, and they can be found easily (see work of Posa, Dirac, Ore, etc.)

For instance, the following is true: *If every vertex of the graph has degree at least n/2*, then the graph has a Hamiltonian path. You can in fact find one in O(n<sup>2</sup>), or IIRC even O(n log n) if you do it more cleverly.
[Rough sketch: First, just connect all vertices in some "Hamiltonian" cycle, nevermind if the edges are actually in the graph. Now for every edge (v,w) of your cycle that is not actually in the graph, consider the rest of the cycle: v...w. As deg(v)+deg(w)>=n, there exist consecutive x,y in your list (in that order) such that w is a neighbour of x and v is a neighbour of y. [Proof: Consider {the set of all neighbours of w} and {the set of all successors in your list of neighbours of v}; they must intersect.] Now change your cycle [v...xy...wv] to [vy...wx...v] instead, it has at least one less invalid edge, so you'll need at most n iterations to get a true Hamiltonian cycle. More details [here](http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~perouz/cs251/documents/solutions6/solutions6.html).]

BTW: if what you are looking for is just a walk that includes every *edge* once, it's called an Eulerian walk and for graphs that have it (number of vertices of odd degree is 0 or 2), one can quite easily be found in polynomial time (fast).

Answer (score 3):

It's NP complete. But if you do manage to find a good method, let me know and I'll show you how to get rich.

Answer (score 2):

Finding a better algorithm for the shortest is unlikely, as it is NP hard.  But there are some heuristics that you could try, and perhaps you might want to consult your lecture notes for those ;) .

For less complexity you could find a short(ish) walk using the greedy algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm.. this depends on what your definitions are. An hamiltonian path is certainly NP-complete. However, an hamiltonian walk which can visit edges and vertices more than once (yes it's still called hamiltonian so long as you add the walk bit at the end) can be calculated in O(p^2logp) or O(max(c^2plogp, |E|)) so long as your graph meets a certain condition which Dirac first conjectured and the Takamizawa proved. See Takamizawa (1980) "An algorithm for finding a short closed spanning walk in a graph".

Paul

Comment: It's amazing that the only correct answer to the OP's question did not get upvoted at  all ...

Answer (score 1):

Depending on just how the graphs you're working with are generated you might be able to get expected polynomial time against a random instance by doing greedy path extension and then a random edge swap when that gets stuck.

This works well against randomly generated relatively sparse graphs guaranteed to have a Hamiltonian walk.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a good answer, much better than the "ha ha NP complete" non-answers that don't tell you what you *can* do.

Answer (score 1):

My Query: Show that a search problem RHAM for finding a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph G is 
self-reducible 
A search problem R is self-reducible if it is Cook-reducible to a decision problem
`SR={ x : R(x) ≠ ∅ }`